# Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.iOS appstore publishing issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm stuck with the following problem for second day in a row.

I'm trying to publish compiled ipa package with Application Loader (delivered with xcode 9.2, ver. 3.7).

I'm getting following errors every time I try to upload.

> description length:861761
>
> ERROR ITMS-90680: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable."

[image: screenshot]

I've tried to compile with many options modified, always same result.

What I've already deduced is:

- I need to setup linker properly, to reduce the size of binary, currently for the development process it was turned off.
- There were some issues reported with app package containing files with filename beginning same as executable name (may that be the case?)
- Verified with lipo it can retrieve correct architectures from main binary

(Forgot to mention I've already read every possible page/topic/post on first 10 pages of google search for above errors)

I'm willing to provide as much info and details as I can, trying to solve this issue for second day in a row non-stop really grinds my gears.

Comment: `There were some issues reported with app package containing files with filename beginning same as executable name` What files? Reported by Apple? The build/archive/publish process?

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. I meant I've read this <somewhere> (forum post) that *.app package inside *.ipa cannot contain files with name beginning same as Bundle executable name.

Comment: And is that the case with your `.ipa`?

Comment: No longer, but I still get the same errors, so that is probably unrelated.